# R data.table convert price to returns by criteria

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

Hi I have a intra day data table with the following columns :

```
 date, stock_id, timestamp, price
```

First I added keys to order this properly :

```
setkeyv( my_table, c('stock_id','date','timestamp'))
```

The data looks like :

```
     date      timestamp    stock_id      price       
 2011-01-04    1.294128e+12    7          3402.0     
 2011-01-04    1.294129e+12    7          3402.5     
 2011-01-04    1.294129e+12    7          3407.5
```

Now I would like to convert the stock_price to returns and log returns.

Could you please point to an efficient/elegant way to do this in R and data.table grouping without resorting to loops?

Many thanks in advance, I'm very new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, you've asked something that is most easily done in the latest version (v1.8.1) on R-Forge repo using a new feature: `:=` by group.

How about (untested) :

```
my_table[, logret:=c(NA,diff(log(stock_price))), by=stock_name]
```

To install v1.8.1 from R-Forge without compiling from source, you need to be running R 2.15.0 or later and then just type :

```
install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: It now works after changing to : dt[, logret:=c(NA,diff(log(stock_price))), by=list(stock_id,date)] Thank you all for your help. Extremely elegant and fast solution. This is why R is awesome !!!